# How does CMS block-placement/page-creation work?

Tags: php, laravel, drupal, content-management-system

I am quite experienced in PHP (OOP), and various other web programming languages, but i can't seem to wrap my head around how CMS block building really works?

When I build myself a CMS, i make static pages (poor idea, i know). But how does one make dynamic blocks/pages, like in Drupal/EPiServer?

Are the block's markup stored in the database, or references to the block-file? I'm not talking "how to code it", but more like, what's the analogy/method?

In short, i'd like to make a CMS that's able to:

- Drag'n'drop blocks
- Create new pages (dynamic routing)

I know this is poor described, so feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of Drupal (7) the complete page is build of blocks. The page itself is composed of regions and block are placed into regions. The configuration of which block appears in which region is stored in the DB.

The content of each block is build using it own callback function known to the system (there is mapping between the blocks and their rendering code) so the markups of the blocks themselves are not stored in the DB (or anywhere). Instead, when the page is build, the markup for each block is generate using content from the database (or any other sources).

The markups for all blocks is then injected into the main page template for the page rendering. The page template take cars of the markup needed for the blocks and region layout.

Comment: Cheers! This answered my question perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer of this question is really a broad, and can be as complex or simple depend on the demand.

Here is how database driven or Dynamic Website works:

1. You/User can add or edit via a text editor(similar to this SO editor) or any kind of user input
2. On save, the user input will get saved to database (Please make sure to use either `PDO` or `MYSQLI`, and also `HTML PURIFIER` if you plan to serve HTML codes to end user. this will save user from XSS attack.
3. Now that the data is saved on the database you can create a page called `view.php`, this will serve as the dynamic content page.
4. Now for displaying data it is recommended to use `GET` method, it will make sure the search engine will be able to index it. also you can copy the link and give it to other user.

   For example you URL may look like this `http://fakesite1213.com/view.php?content_id=23`, notice the `content_id=23` part this is the `GET` request.
5. Even though the database and the get request is set, we still need to get the data and show it to the USER. for that we can use simple queries like:

   ```
   //open database connection
   try {
      $dbcon = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';
      dbname='. SITE_DB_NAME . ';
      charset=utf8', SITE_DB_USER, SITE_DB_PASS);
   } catch (Exception $e) {
   }

   // use try catch block for queries.
   // I am using pdo, by using
   try {
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE contentid=:contentid";
       $statement = $dbcon->prepare($sql);
       $statement->bindValue(':contentid', $_GET['content_id']);
       $statement->execute();
       $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

       if (count($result) > 0)
       {
           var_dump($result);
       }
   } catch (Exception $e) {}
   ```

The code is pretty simple and straightforward. if your database table has a column name `contentid` it will run a match against the `$_GET['content_id']` which is from the get method(the url). when we get some match, we `var_dump` it. You need to use `echo` and also `$result` most likely will return an array.

There is also other way to use ajax and json, but this is the basic idea

Comment: Thanks alot for the detailed response. However, i was more thinking about the analogy behind storing the HTML blocks and placement? :)